# It's working only on simulator, but isn't working on Device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm working on sample project for learning core animation. I have problem with my device, I wrote simple project and it's conatins just one viewcontroller and this viewcontroller's view contains just two layer, each layer have .png image backgrounds (actually 700 x 700 px) and these images contains semi transparent content.

You can download example project from [here](http://fatihyasar.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/FW.zip)

This project working perfectly on simulator but isn't working on Iphone. I have't seen any error or some thing like that. I have seen empty sreen on device.

Could someone give me suggestions about that please ?

Thank you

Comment: Just a tip, remove the "build" folder from your projects when uploading somewhere. This significantly decreases the file size. ;)

Comment: SanHolo thank you for this trick it will be usefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image file name is "Clouds1.png " but you load it:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"clouds2.png"] CGImage];
```

Problem is that file system on iPhone is case sensitive and on MacOS is not. So you must be careful with file names.

Comment: Vladimir you are life saver as allways :) 
Thank you very much